# why is this conflicting type declaration?

Tags: c

I have compilation problem as follows. Header file `abc.h` is included by `abc.c`.

In the header file, i have this

```
extern char **foo;
```

in the source file, i have this

```
char *foo[] = { ".mp3", ".mp4" };
```

Yet i get a compilation error from GCC:

```
abc.c:23:7: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
In file included from abc.c:18:0:
abc.h:64:15: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
```

Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One is an array of pointers while the other is a pointer to a pointer. Very different objects. Try declaring it as an array:

```
extern char *foo[];
```

Comment: @KingWeeWee Things work differently in a function declaration :-)

Comment: @KingWeeWee: you were mistaken, they're not the same type. When the compiler sees an external symbol with a type "array of X of unspecified size", what it's actually going to link against is the address of the array, which starts at the same location as its first element. Nevertheless the type is different from the type of a pointer to that first element.

Answer (score 0):

`extern char[]` and `extern char *` are two different

And for **extern** declaration is supposed to match up with one definition.

```
extern char **foo;
```

**matches**

```
char **foo;
```

**does not match**

```
char *foo[];
```

**same thing**

```
extern char *foo[];  /* matches */  
char *foo[];
```